# Issues setting image height

Tags: html, css, height

So I was wondering if there is a way to set an image's height to 75% of the height of it's parent container without using JavaScript?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Give the container an absolute height and sure, `height:75%` will work on the `img`:

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x1"/> <!-- This is a 1px high image -->
</div>
```

```css
div {
    height:100px; /* Absolute height on container. */
    width:100px;
    background:#f00; /* I've used this to illustrate that the image fills 75%. */
}

img {
    width:100%; /* Force the width to 100% to prevent scaling. */
    height:75%; /* Height percentage declaration. */
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ktes/1/).

Comment: So would it work if the container didn't have an absolute height? Also, sorry for the delay in response--just saw your message!

Comment: @Drew percentages scale to things. If no absolute height is available then there isn't anything to scale to. This applies to all elements, not just images.

Comment: Gotcha. So in this case if I set the parent container's height to 100%, wouldn't that just set it to 100% the height of the page?

Comment: For that to work you'd also need to specify 100% height on your `html` and `body` elements. :)

Answer (score 0):

No because that would involve a dynamic computation which is not the purpose of HTML, but is exactly the purpose of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The relative unit must have a point to be calculated from so in this case parent element must have a set height